# How to write a search for a field regardless of its case?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

There is a filtering on the site that works to find a value by a public property:
? propertyName = SomeName & propertyValue = SomeValue;

Now I'm wondering what if, for example, if an incorrect name of this property (SomENAme1) is entered -> what would the web application still call filtering by the SomeName property? That is, whatever the case does not matter, and that the entered word is matched at least completely with the filter property?

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyLabel, string propertyValue)
        
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyLabel))
            {
                return source;
            }
 
            var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                      .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property.Name == propertyLabel)
                                      .Select(property => property.Name);
 
            //var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = item => false;
 
            foreach (var name in propertyNames)
            {
               // if (propertyLabel.Contains(name))
               // {
                    //propertyLabel = name;
                //}
 
                predicate = predicate.Or(GetExpression<T>(name, propertyValue));
            }
 
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```

I've triend in foreach loop:

```
if (propertyLabel.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
{
    propertyLabel = name;
}
```

But it doesnt work, even just for lowercase...

Comment: In the `Where` of your LINQ you already filtered for an exact match.

Comment: ^^ Klaus is right. Please check the contents of your `propertyNames` collection. You'll probably find, they are not even in there. Solution would be to cut out the `&& property.Name == propertyLabel` and check later ... _or_ do a case-insenstivie check _here_. This may be intersting for you: [case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#case-insensitive-ordinal-comparisons)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var propertyNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                              .Where(property => property.PropertyType == typeof(string)
                                && propertyLabel.ToLower().Contains(property.Name.ToLower()))
                              .Select(property => property.Name);
```